# Good term for remaining items after filtering

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I am working on an research app that allows user to specify topics that he is interested in. Say the user is interested in Sports. I have built a filter, that automatically classifies news articles into two categories:

- Useful Articles (Remaining articles) -- lists articles from the topic that the user is interested in
- Useless Articles (Filtered articles) -- all the leftover articles

Can you suggest a nice term for Remaining articles ? Or better terms for both filtered, remaining articles ?

Edit 1: By useless I mean a subject that I am not interested in.

Edit 2: I will be using these two terms on my website in a dropdown menu so that people can select whether they want to see Useless articles or Useful articles.

Edit 3: The secrecy behind useful wasn't intentional

Comment: t depends on what you mean by useless. Does it mean poorly written? Does it mean it contains a subject that doesn't interest you? What criteria do you use to perform the filtering? There could be many terms, *essential-inessential*? *pertinent-irrelevant*? Please give some context.

Comment: By "nice," do you mean that you will be telling the authors of the "useless" articles that you categorized their articles this way, and that you want to break the news gently?  Or do you just mean you want a good term for this?

Comment: Just modified the question

Comment: I think you need to reveal the attributes of 'useful' articles.

Comment: The opposite of _junk_ is considered to be _non-junk_ by quite a few people, according to a Google search.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Junk is good. But what is the opposite of Junk (non-junk is not the right word)

Comment: The 2 options may be "Selected topics" and "Unselected topics".

Comment: Well, one could always use "precipitate" (noun).  ("Filtrate" is usually used to refer to the liquid that makes it through a filter, to my recollection.)

Comment: If you were interested in having three levels of interest, you could use "of interest"/"of little interest"/"of no interest."

Comment: 'What is the opposite of junk?' assumes that there is such a word. 'Non-junk' seems to be acquiring word status to fill a lacuna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Articles that meet the user's criteria: *relevant articles*

Articles that fail to meet to user's criteria are therefore not relevant articles; depending on the context, they might also be called *irrelevant,* *non-relevant,* or, as suggested by sumelic, *other.*

Comment: Or maybe just "other articles"

Answer (score 2):

Try `matched` vs `unmatched`.

[Matched](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/matched) from thefreedictionary.com (*v.tr.*):

> 3. To find or produce a counterpart to

Answer (score 0):

I like "filtrate" for the remaining USEFUL articles. (Although it seems terribly geeky outside of the scientific community, I thought of "elution" for the original hodge-podge of articles. The filtering process is then the "eluent," leaving you with the "residue" and the filtrate, but I'm that kind of geek, so ...)

Comment: Nice, but a count noun would fit better, I suspect.  Non-count filtrate is the result of filtering a (non-count) substance.  Perhaps we should be speaking of screens rather than filters.

Answer (score 0):

*found articles*, *matching articles*, and *search hits* all refer to articles that match the filter predicates (criteria).